# Is specifiying a work-tree in a .git file supported?

Tags: git

I have this in a `.git` **file** :

```
gitdir: path\to\git-dir
```

I would like to also add the work-tree dir, something ala

```
worktree: path\to\work-tree
```

Is that supported by git ?

Comment: If both the gitdir and the worktree are different from the directory containing the `.git` file, then what is that directory still needed for? I mean why couldn't you just move the `.git` file to the root of the worktree?

Comment: I'm doing backups using git and that way I can open the backup with GitHub desktop for visual purposes. Does that answer your question ? Also that way I don't have `.git` files everywhere. I'm swiss I like to keep things clean you know ?

Comment: Git is not a good choice as a backup tool.  If you want a backup tool that uses Git repositories, use bup, which has some modifications to make it perform and function much better on a wide variety of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem [for future ref here : [https://rakhesh.com/coding/how-to-move-separate-the-git-folder-out-of-your-working-tree](https://rakhesh.com/coding/how-to-move-separate-the-git-folder-out-of-your-working-tree/)].

A work-tree can be specified [not in a .git file but] in the git folder config file; by adding a `worktree` line. Easy as that :)

Example `git-dir/config` file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
>>  worktree = <path/to/work-tree>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The `.git` file (when there is a `.git` file) must occupy the top level of the working tree, so if you *have* a `.git` file, the directory in which that `.git` file lives *is* the working tree.  So there's no point in listing the working tree path: it's implied by the fact that you used that path to open the file named `.git`.  This does of course mean that you have to remember the path you used to open the file named `.git`, which in some circumstances is a bit of a pain point, but that's *why* the answer is no.

Comment: ok but no solution to my problem here - I have just found one. thanks anyway.

Comment: Note that you found an answer to a different question than the one you asked. You've just rediscovered the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/641754). :-)